# Passing a variable received by flask through HTTP post to JavaScript in html template on flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, opencv, flask

So I'm creating a python app that counts detected objects using OpenCV then passing the counter variable to Flask server using the following HTTP post request:

```
requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000', json = {'count': count})
```

, the flask sever receives the variable then pass it to a JavaScript within the html template, here is the code of flask server:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    content = request.get_json(silent=True) 
    if content :
        cnt = content.get('count') #get JSON from OpenCV every time the count is updated 
        print cnt # here it prints the variable to the cmd and show me the count update
    return render_template("test.html", cnt = cnt); #here the value is passed as zero ?!

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and when I run the 'test.html' template it only show me the 'cnt' variable = 0, although I'm getting the updated value constantly from my OpenCV code to my flask server.

here is the script part of my 'test.html'

```
   <p>People count: <span id="counti"></span></p>
<script>
var countn = '{{cnt}}';
document.getElementById('counti').innerHTML = countn
</script>
```

I want my 'count' variable to pass smoothly from OpenCV and receive into my Javascript to be able to make my web-app able to make decisions based on the count of objects observed by OpenCV.

What is the optimal way to do this ?

I really appreciate your help!